# C Warning passing argument 2 of ‘getopt’ from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c

I write a function with `getopt()` to get options from the command line. When I compile it, I get this Warning:

```
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
csim.c: In function ‘getArg’:
csim.c:157: error: passing argument 2 of ‘getopt’ from incompatible 
pointer type /usr/include/getopt.h:152: note: expected ‘char * const*’ 
but argument is of type ‘const char **’
```

Here is the C code:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(){
}

int getArg(int argc, char const *argv[], int *verbose, int *ps, 
    int *pE, int *pb, char *traceFileName){
    int arg;
    int argCount;
    while ((arg = getopt(argc, argv, "vs:E:b:t:")) != -1){
        switch (arg){
            case 'v':
            *verbose = 1;
            break;

            default:
            printf("%s\n", "Illegal command arguments, please input again");
            exit(-1);
            break;
        }
    }

    if(argCount < 4){
        printf("%s\n", "Illegal command arguments, please input again");
            exit(-1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, as the error says, you're passing a `const char **` where a `char * const*` is expected. Specifically you're passing `argv` (which has the wrong type) to getopt. You could fix this by changing the type of `argv`.

```
int getArg(int argc, char * const argv[], int *verbose, int *ps, int *pE, int *pb, char *traceFileName)
```

Comment: thanks davmac! i see that in some code main() function is like main(int argc, char **argv). so, what's the difference with char * const argv[], char const* argv[], and char **argv ?

Comment: `char * const argv[]` is an unmodifiable array of `char *` values. It can be converted to a pointer (specifically a `char * const *`, i.e. a pointer to unmodifiable `char *` values). `char const argv[]` would be an unmodifiable array of char values. `char **argv` is a pointer-to-pointers-to-char; it can be treated as an array of `char *`.

Answer (score 0):

It is the way your function has declared argv. You changed the constness. The error message is telling you what is wrong.